# Does Plesk compile its own versions of software like cPanel?

Tags: packages

I am getting a new dedicated server with CentOS 6 and have the option of getting Plesk 11.x for free.

I know, [sysadmins are supposed to hate panels](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/development/we_hate_plesk_and_cpanel), but it would make the client's life much easier (and fewer support requests for me) if Plesk were installed.

I have no previous experience with Plesk and would like to know if like cPanel, Plesk compiles its own versions of software too. If it does then it would be a no-no in my book, as it would complicate things a bit too much for me. Having to deal with custom versions of software as opposed to standard ones would just tip the balance against Plesk.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Only the lowend sysadms hate them. High-end sysadms know, for what are they useful and for what they aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plesk has own packages of courier-imap, proftpd, nginx, phpMyAdmin, Horde, roundcube, phpPgAdmin, pear, logrotate, drweb, Kaspersky, SpamAssassin, fail2ban, ModSecurity2.

Since Plesk 12 own PHP 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 version packages shipped with Plesk for Centos 6, Centos 7, Ubuntu 14.04.

Additionally Since PLesk 12.5 own PHP(5.2-5.6) packages will be shipped for Redhat 6, RedHat 7, Debian 7, Ubuntu 12.04.